# Unable to write custom queries using Spring WebFlux and ReactiveCassandraRepository

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra, reactive-programming, datastax-enterprise, spring-data-cassandra

I am trying to connect Spring WebFlux (spring boot version 2.0.6) with datastax Cassandra DSE3.x. But when I am trying to query Cassandra Table using ReactiveCassandraRepository with custom query I am getting following error. However I am able to get count of the records from that table.

> Unsupported feature with the native protocol V1 (which is currently in use): Binary values are not supported; nested exception is com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.UnsupportedFeatureException: Unsupported feature with the native protocol V1 (which is currently in use): Binary values are not supported"

My Repository Code is

```
public interface SystemLookupReactiveRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository<SystemLookup, String> {

@AllowFiltering
@Query("{SELECT * FROM \"SystemLookup\" WHERE LookupId = ?0 ALLOW FILTERING}")
Mono<SystemLookup> findByLookupId(String lookupId);}
```

My POM file is :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra-reactive</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-reactor-netty</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Can you share a Cassandra section of the POM file?

Comment: Added the POM file

Comment: What happens if you modify `SystemLookupReactiveRepository` to extend different library-specific [repository interfaces](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/2.0.6.RELEASE/reference/html/#cassandra.reactive.repositories.libraries)?

Comment: Same issue I am getting with other Repositories too

Comment: Ok. The only other [link](https://groups.google.com/a/lists.datastax.com/forum/#!topic/spark-connector-user/PUWo3PMwNCU) I could find with the same issue. Perhaps you should rewrite the application to use [CassandraTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/cassandra/core/CassandraTemplate.html) instead of the repository. Or update Cassandra [version](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/2.1/manual/native_protocol/).

Comment: Yeah but it doesn't support reactive programming

Comment: What happens if you execute the same query natively (e.g. using `CqlOperations`/`ReactiveCqlOperations`)?

Comment: Yes its working fine with native queries. Thanks